# SVN a symlink pointing to my home directory

Tags: svn

Question: Is it possible to svn a symlink and the link is pointing to something in my home directory so that when my other co-workers performs an svn update they will see the symlink pointing to their home directory instead?

Example:

In this directory: /home/arthur/scripts/test/perl, I want to create a symlink that is something like this: ln -s /home/arthur/scripts/test/ test

So, if I do a ls on /home/arthur/scripts/test/perl, it will show me something like this...

files...
test -> /home/arthur/scripts/test/
files...

But when I try to svn this, my other co-workers sees the symlink as something that is still pointing to my home directory. Is there a way to dynamically have the symlink point to their own home directory instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a relative symlink, not an absolute one.

In /home/arthur/scripts/test/perl:

```
ln -s .. test
```

Why you need to have it named test instead of just pointing to the parent directory is beyond me, but I guess it's because you've only tried to demonstrate the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best plan is probably to add the symlink to svn:ignore and write a script to make the link that you commit to svn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is actually possible.

One way you could do it is to have each developer create a symlink from their own home directory to a place with a common name.

Say you did this:
  ln -s /home/arthur /home/devhome

And everyone else did, too.  Then you could add the symlink like this:

ln -s /home/devhome/scripts/test test

That shoud resolve to the proper file as long as each developer creates the /home/devhome symlink first.